# How can I merge these two similar methods

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-duplication

I'm using Entity Framework and have PERSON entities that contain multiple EMAIL and PHONE entities. When updating a person I have a helper method that updates addresses and a helper method that updates email addresses. I can't figure out a good way to eliminate all the code duplication between them. My first thought was to use generics, but I can't think of how to do that where I wouldn't end up with an overly complex method that would reduce readability more than than it would increase maintainability. Thank you!

```
private void HandleEmailUpdate(PERSON personEntity, string emailType, string newValue)
{
    var emailEntity = personEntity.EMAILs.FirstOrDefault(h => h.EMAIL_TYPE == emailType);

    if (emailEntity == null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue))
            return;

        var newEmail = new EMAIL
        {
            EMAIL_TYPE = emailType,
            EMAIL_ADDR = newValue,
            SSN = personEntity.SSN,
            PID = personEntity.PID
        };

        personEntity.EMAILs.Add(newEmail);
        _context.Entry(newEmail).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else if (emailEntity.EMAIL_ADDR != newValue)
    {
        if (newValue == "")
        {
            _context.Entry(emailEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Entry(emailEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(new {EMAIL_ADDR = newValue});
            _context.Entry(emailEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}

private void HandlePhoneUpdate(PERSON personEntity, string phoneType, string newValue)
{
    var phoneEntity = personEntity.PHONEs.FirstOrDefault(h => h.PHONE_TYPE == phoneType);

    if (phoneEntity == null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue))
            return;

        var newPhone = new PHONE
        {
            PHONE_TYPE = phoneType,
            PHONE1 = newValue,
            SSN = personEntity.SSN,
            PID = personEntity.PID
        };

        personEntity.PHONEs.Add(newPhone);
        _context.Entry(newPhone).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else if (phoneEntity.PHONE1 != newValue)
    {
        if (newValue == "")
        {
            _context.Entry(phoneEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Entry(phoneEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(new {PHONE1 = newValue});
            _context.Entry(phoneEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: (I censored out names with 'xxx')

```
HandlePhoneUpdate(entity, "ALT", updatedPerson.PhoneAlt);
HandlePhoneUpdate(entity, "CELL", updatedPerson.PhoneCellWork);
HandlePhoneUpdate(entity, "SECOND_CELL", updatedPerson.PhoneCellPersonal);
HandlePhoneUpdate(entity, "xxx", updatedPerson.Phonexxx);
HandlePhoneUpdate(entity, "HOME", updatedPerson.PhoneHome);
HandlePhoneUpdate(entity, "WORK", updatedPerson.PhoneWork);

HandleEmailUpdate(entity, "ALT", updatedPerson.EmailAlt);
HandleEmailUpdate(entity, "xxx", updatedPerson.Emailxxx);
HandleEmailUpdate(entity, "HOME", updatedPerson.EmailPersonal);
HandleEmailUpdate(entity, "xxx", updatedPerson.Emailxxx);
HandleEmailUpdate(entity, "WORK", updatedPerson.EmailWork);
```

Comment: extension methods will remove on of the parameters, like `public void HandleSomething(this PERSON person, string phoneType, string newVal) ` then call it like `person.HandleSomething("asd","asdf"); ` and you can make it like `public void HandeSomething<T> (this PERSON, string Type, string newVal){ if(T is Phone){...}  else if(T is Email)}`

Comment: If EMAIL and PHONE classes don't share a base class then I don't see how you can merge the code and keep the readability and maintainability at the same time without using generics.

Answer (score 0):

If they follow the same rules, makes sense to unify the `Phone` and `Email` class and create a `Contact` class. The `Contact` class would have a `Type` property (Email, Phone, ...), a `Value` property, and others properties if necessary.
This way you can use the same method for both types (Email and Phone): `HandleContactUpdate`